# What's the correct way to have a PC communicate with an Android device over USB these days?

Tags: android, usb

I'm not an Android expect, so forgive me if this is obvious. I admit I would have expected to find the answer to this very quickly, bit I can't really figure out the right answer.

We're developing an Android app in an environment with no wifi. We need to be able to grab some information from the Android device onto a PC, and the only way to physically connect the Android to the PC is via a USB cable. I then need to grab some information (not a lot) from the Android device. Doing it via socket is fine. Grabbing a file from the Android FS somehow is also fine.
I need the solution to be production grade, and as such, ADB (being a debugging tool) does seem like a proper solution. I also read some on the Accessory API, but it seems like it wasn't meant for using with a PC.

What would be the proper way of implementing something like this?

Comment: What a fuss. Put the info in a file. Then everybody with a pc can read it. No adb needed.

Comment: Sorry to create a fuss for you.
And then how do you suggest the PC talks back to the app?
Would you consider this "production grade"? Can you make sure that any android device always maps as a drive on any pc? Can you tell in advance which drive it's going to be?

Comment: You did not not mention all those things before. And new Android devices will never mapp as a drive. They use MTP. As the PC has to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you need more features go for ADB which provides client-server interface between you and the device/emulator through which you can do the following important tasks with various terminal commands.

- Install & uninstall application: `adb install path_to_apk`
- Set up port forwarding: `adb forward tcp:6100 tcp:7100`
- copy files to&from device: `adb pull remote local`, `adb push foo.txt /sdcard/foo.txt`
- Take screenshot and capture video: `adb shell screencap /sdcard/screen.png`
- call packagemanager and activitymanager to know the metadata of apks installed on the device/emulator.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. This won't work for what I'm asking, though. I'm aware of what you can do with ADB, but this is not something you can tell your (non-techy) user to do, nor are you supposed to create a reliable "production worthy" flow using ADB. Imagine a low tech environment where there's a user who uses the Android to collect information, and then needs to offload that data to a PC, without being able to connect the Android to a network.

Answer (score 0):

you said 'in an environment without wifi' did you mean:

1. no actual wifi like the one my machine is connected to right now or no wireless technology at all ( both infrared, bluetooth, wifi, NFC ...)?
2. Please detail more on your use case.
3. Is the act of connecting part of the applications usage flow during dev or rather during normal usage by clients( production)?

Though kinda feel like from what you are saying it's the normal usage flow after production. Just wanna be sure.
Waiting on your reply.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. 
1. No wifi means there is no wifi network around that the Android device can connect to, and see the PC (and communicate via TCP/IP).

2. The android device collects data in its normal course. Then it needs to offload that data to a PC, and have some form of handshake with the PC to make sure the PC got it.

3. You're right - production it is. You collect data with the Android device, then need to offload it to a PC (with no wifi or network available, etc.)